babylonjs virtual joystick and scene actions
I have a babylon.js project. I am using virtual joystick.
` var leftJoystick = new BABYLON.VirtualJoystick(true);
BABYLON.VirtualJoystick.Canvas.style.zIndex = "4";

var movespeed = 5
scene.onBeforeRenderObservable.add(()=>{
    if(leftJoystick.pressed){
       const moveX = leftJoystick.deltaPosition.x * (engine.getDeltaTime()/1000) * movespeed;
       const moveZ = leftJoystick.deltaPosition.y * (engine.getDeltaTime()/1000) * movespeed;
        camera.position.x+=moveX
        camera.position.z+=moveZ
    }
})`

but i don't click another models how to solve this problem.
I tried define touch border with html and css but not worked.
